# how do I access this StripeCharge mapper object?

Tags: c#

stripe.com sends me this to my ashx file

```
{
"type": "charge.refunded",
"livemode": false,
"object": "event",
"created": 1326853478,
"id": "evt_00000000000000",
"data": {
 "object": {
  "livemode": false,
  "fee_details": [
    {
      "application": null,
      "type": "stripe_fee",
      "amount": 0,
      "currency": "usd",
      "description": "Stripe processing fees"
    }
  ],
  "amount_refunded": 0,
  "invoice": null,
  "failure_message": null,
  "object": "charge",
  "created": 1355641115,
  "amount": 0,
  "customer": null,
  "currency": "usd",
  "card": {
    "address_state": null,
    "exp_year": 2012,
    "type": "Visa",
    "address_country": null,
    "country": "US",
    "address_line1": null,
    "fingerprint": "thIB5TIJqKMnqdMm",
    "address_line2": null,
    "last4": "4242",
    "object": "card",
    "cvc_check": "pass",
    "address_city": null,
    "address_zip_check": null,
    "name": null,
    "address_zip": null,
    "exp_month": 12,
    "address_line1_check": null
  },
  "id": "ch_00000000000000",
  "dispute": null,
  "paid": true,
  "refunded": true,
  "fee": 0,
  "description": null
}
}
}
```

and then I use code from
https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net
which shows to do this:

```
var json = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
var stripeEvent = StripeEventUtility.ParseEvent(json); 
var StripeCharge = Stripe.Mapper<StripeCharge>
                   .MapFromJson(stripeEvent.Data.Object.ToString());
```

but now how do I find for example, amount_refunded or description from the stripeCharge var?

Answer (score 0):

StripeCharge.CustomerId.ToString();
the problem for me was not understanding that StripeCharge when declared as a var
is a dynamic expression that will get populated at runtime.

so when I type StripeCharge dot in visual studio I didn't see any properties.\
so I didn't think it was working.

Answer (score 0):

Digg into members of the stripecharge class. It will be good if you can paste your code along with the classes (in case your issue is open). I can see here you have answered uour question so plz make this point clear too